# What is the difference between "provisioned" and "provided"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, terminology, comparison

I'm reading this article and they wrote:

> After the identity is created, the credentials are provisioned onto
>   the instance.

What I understand is that the credentials will be given to then instance and when I looked up provision I've ended up at:

> something provided;
>
> the providing or supplying of something, especially of food or other necessities.

So what is the difference between provided and provisioned? Can't we say

> After the identity is created, the credentials are **provided** onto
>   the instance.

And have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are in the IT domain where specialist terminology is used. To my eyes the phrase in question is slightly odd, but acceptable in an IT context.

The general concept of supplying credentials is frequently referred to as provisioning. See [this article](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/user-account-provisioning) as a random example. In my experience we would say:

> Oh, I've nearly finished, just a bit of provisioning to do now ...

We would not use provide or its derivitives in this way.

In this environment where **provisioning** is widely understood,

> the credentials are provisioned onto the instance

we might say

> the instance is provisioned with the credential

but I'm not sure it's better. In the mind of the person doing the job they have created a set of credentials and are applying them to the instance, rather like attaching a bit to a drill; the focus is selecting the right implement, the credentials, so that dominates the phrase.

Comment: So you'd say that "attached to" is the underlying meaning?

Comment: Yes, but with the additional possibility that **the same** credential might also be applied to other similar servers.

Comment: I remember my English teacher saying "artistry" was incorrect and the term should be "art". In neither that nor this case do I see an intrinsic reason for the difference, but English is funny that way. And I too am in IT :)

Answer (score 1):

The author there is using language rather freely. The verb **provisioned *onto*** doesn't really exist in English.  The verb **provision** is transitive, taking a direct object and  an optional prepositional phrase introduced by **with**:

> Headquarters provisioned the rescue team with food, blankets, and satellite radios.

In this context, where a computing object is supplied to a class instance which presumably then encapsulates that object, there is really no meaningful difference between **provided to** and **supplied to** or even **sent to**.  I don't see what the preposition **onto** adds to our understanding, and it is not idiomatic with that verb.

Comment: I think this is a very idiomatic space; custom and practice are not always logical. I would not use provided, but rather provisioned. One possible difference is that we provide to a person or organisation, they are active in receiving. We provision onto a device or machine, which has a more passive role.

Comment: I would say that it is a very *unidiomatic space* with its own idioms created by members of the space who don't work much with natural language. :-)

Comment: guilty as charged ;-)